# Flink - How to serialize a POJO to Kafka Sink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to KafkaSink my DataStream and for that I'm using the below code:

```
     KafkaSink<Events> sink = KafkaSink.<Events>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(LOCAL_KAFKA_BROKER)
        .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
                .setTopic(OUTPUT_KAFKA_TOPIC)
                .setValueSerializationSchema(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .build())
        .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        .build();
```

Here, SimpleStringSchema() is not suitable as I'm returning a POJO of Events. Here is the POJO I've been using.

```
    public Events(Date windowStart, Date windowEnd,
                    String metric, String eventId,
                    long count) {
        this.windowStart = windowStart;
        this.windowEnd = windowEnd;
        this.metric = metric;
        this.eventId = eventId;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Date getWindowStart() {
        return windowStart;
    }

    public void setWindowStart(Date windowStart) {
        this.windowStart = windowStart;
    }

    public Date getWindowEnd() {
        return windowEnd;
    }

    public void setWindowEnd(Date windowEnd) {
        this.windowEnd = windowEnd;
    }

    public String getMetric() {
        return metric;
    }

    public void setMetric(String metric) {
        this.metric = metric;
    }

    public String getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(String eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Events{");
        sb.append("windowStart=").append(windowStart);
        sb.append(", windowEnd=").append(windowEnd);
        sb.append(", metric=").append(metric);
        sb.append(", eventId=").append(eventId);
        sb.append(", count=").append(count);
        sb.append("}");

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

For the POJO, I'm not able to come up with the SerializationSchema, that can be used here. I tried the below:

```
    public class EventsSerializationSchema implements DeserializationSchema<Events>, SerializationSchema<Events> {

        private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        private String topic;

        public EventsSerializationSchema(){
        }

        public EventsSerializationSchema(String topic) {
            this.topic = topic;
        }

        @Override
        public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(
                final Events events, @Nullable final Long timestamp) {
            try {
                //if topic is null, default topic will be used
                return new ProducerRecord<>(topic, objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(events));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not serialize record: " + events, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

But, this is not working as I'm not sure on how to serialize this. Can someone please help on this?
P.S: As I'm using Flink 1.14, FlinkKafkaPublisher is deprecated in this version.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, did you try replacing `new SimpleStringSchema` with `new EventsSerializationSchema`?

Comment: Otherwise, `SimpleStringSchema` would work absolutely fine if you first `.map()` some `DataStream<Event>` into a `DataStream<String>` and _then_ wrote to Kafka.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that.. `EventSerializationSchema` is not complete as it doesn't have the serialize method. That's where I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: You tried the solution in my second comment, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EventsSerializationSchema` is implementing the wrong interface. You want to implement either `SerializationSchema` or `KafkaSerializationSchema`, depending on whether you'd rather implement

`byte[] serialize(T element)`

or

`ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(T element, @Nullable Long timestamp)`.

See [KafkaProducerJob.java](https://github.com/alpinegizmo/flink-mobile-data-usage/blob/main/src/main/java/com/ververica/flink/example/datausage/KafkaProducerJob.java) and [UsageRecordSerializationSchema.java](https://github.com/alpinegizmo/flink-mobile-data-usage/blob/main/src/main/java/com/ververica/flink/example/datausage/records/UsageRecordSerializationSchema.java) for an example.